# How come Xubuntu and Ubuntu Unity are not yet providing downloads for 22.04.2?

Tags: xubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I'm trying to always seed the latest official Ubuntu LTS point releases on BitTorrent, and I have also done so with the 22.04.2 release.

However, for [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/download/) and [Ubuntu Unity](https://ubuntuunity.org/download/) in particular, it seems the download hasn't yet updated to 22.04.2 (as per March 8, 2023), and it's still 22.04.1 that are available as official downloads.

Can anyone explain why this might be? And also on a more general level, it was my impression that as an official Ubuntu flavor, you have an obligation to bump to the latest point release, but maybe I'm wrong?

*I'm not trying to point the finger here, I'm just curious why the latest point release have seemingly been delayed for Xubuntu and Ubuntu Unity.*

Comment: Ubuntu Unity 22.10 was the first *official* release which explains that one (*possibly, not official flavor*)...    I just made an enquiry on #xubuntu-devel, so it'll be fixed the moment someone with *rights* is able to I suspect....

Comment: I also made a request on *Ubuntu Unity Discuss* (telegram) and the response back said Ubuntu Unity 22.04.2 has **not yet been released** due to technical issues... thus the reason why it's not updated...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - so there are explanations for both releases then. 

Comment: (took too long to add to prior *Ubuntu Unity* comment; but the response I got was from https://launchpad.net/~maik-adamietz  (who I know of as Maik; took me awhile to find his lp page sorry)  Ubuntu Member etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ubuntu Unity 22.04.2** has not yet been released...

Due to *technical difficulties* the release of Ubuntu Unity 22.04.2 has been delayed.  The page will be updated post-release.

This detail comes from [Maik](https://launchpad.net/%7Emaik-adamietz) (Ubuntu member), who also stated any users of Ubuntu Unity 22.04 LTS that have applied all security fixes & upgrades, will already be using Ubuntu Unity 22.04.2 LTS.  It's only the ISO itself that has been delayed.

**Xubuntu 22.04.2 LTS**

As @matigo has already stated, you can download Xubuntu 22.04.2 LTS already using the link (*due to changes made on cdimage.ubuntu.com actually*), however according to [Unit193](https://launchpad.net/%7Eunit193) the Xubuntu team are having issues with WordPress that has made them unable (*currently*) to correct that page.

Comment: Great explanation for anyone else trying to figure out how to get the latest point releases for these flavors.

Comment: My discussion with the Ubuntu Unity team was over telegram (*their choice of comms*) and with Xubuntu it was over IRC

Comment: I hadn't actually noticed it @ArturMeinild... I had noted complaints about wordpress on #xubuntu-devel channels but had not seen the importance...  I had no idea about Ubuntu Unity 22.04.2 though  (*if i noticed discussion on #ubuntu-flavors re: that, it just escaped me...  once I'd published the Ubuntu News posts (where Ubuntu Unity isn't mentioned due to respin still at 22.04) I just forgot jammy.2*)

Answer (score 3):

For Xubuntu, this looks like it's just the main landing page that has not been updated. Using one of the mirror download links will show the 22.04.2 `.iso` and `.torrent` file:

[image: Xubuntu Download Mirrors]

This may require a quick note to the development team in their IRC channel

Comment: Good catch!! 

Comment: I've already made request on #xubuntu-devel... Unit193 has already responded they're having issues with WordPress thus the lack of update thus far....